# Can't reply to a message discord py slash command using cogs

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am struggling with sending a basic reply in discord.py with a cog. The problem is that the bot keeps pending and eventually breaks.

The problem:

[image]

Here is the code snippet of my cog:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class Example(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("ChatGPT cog connected.")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def sync(self, ctx) -> None:
        fmt = await ctx.bot.tree.sync(guild=ctx.guild)
        await ctx.send(f"Synced {len(fmt)} commands")

    @app_commands.command(name="ping", description="desc")
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.reply("pong")
```

And here is the code snippet of the main file:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from tools.config import TOKEN
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Success: Bot is connected to Discord")

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
        if filename.endswith("py"):
            await client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    await load()
    await client.start(TOKEN)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two ways to respond to it in cogs:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

class Slash(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @app_commands.command(name="test")
    async def test(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message('test successful')
    
    @commands.hybrid_command(name='asd', with_app_command=True)
    async def asd(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.reply("Test was good!")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Slash(bot))
```

And you can make all two responses ephemeral with adding `ephemeral=True` after the content.

Answer (score 0):

switched to pycord and everything just works ‍♂️